# why 'echo --help' doesn't give me help page of echo?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I tried 'man echo' in Bash and it told me that 'echo --help' will display help then exit, and similarly, that 'echo --version' will output version and exit. But why it doesn't work ? 'echo --help' just simply prints  '--help' literally.

Comment: Note that production of a help message by `echo --help` is a **bug**. Imagine what happens if you do: `printf "The option you entered is: " ; echo "$opt"` and the shell variable `opt` happens to be contain the text `--help`. Per the POSIX standard, `echo` is not permitted to behave in this way, but the GNU echo is obnoxiously non-conforming.

Comment: @R.. So `echo -e` and `echo -n` is also a bug, by your logic?

Comment: @Tyilo: See the specification in POSIX, or my coverage of the issue here: http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html

Comment: @R.. Imagine what happens if you do: printf "The option you entered is: " ; echo "$opt" and the shell variable opt happens to be contain the text -e or -n.

Comment: @Tyilo: Rather than re-explaining it I liked to a page where I already explained the answer to that question.

Comment: @R.: your interpretation if POSIX is not correct. POSIX requires full `XSI` compliance except when you are on a small embedded platform. An `echo` that supports `-e`  or `--help` is always non-complant and an `echo` that supports `-n` is noncompliant on a non-embedded platform.

Comment: @schily: I've seen several people claim that but it does not match the text: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html 2.1.1 ¶1&2 clearly use "shall support" for POSIX Conformance requirements and "may support" for XSI Conformance requirements. Morally, POSIX is the stuff any OS, even a non-unix-like one, should be able to agree on, and XSI is the stuff for a system that wants to look like a unix dinosaur. :-)

Comment: For other reasons (whether a shell needs to support the useless `fc` command), I asked Geoff Clare who is the author of the POSIX certification test suite and he explained that a platform that does not support all `XSI` enhancements may only be certified as a small embedded platform.

Comment: I think this question is up there with vim jail meme :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`man echo` relates to the [`echo` program](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). GNU `echo` [supports](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) a `--help` option, as do some others. When you run `echo` in Bash you instead get [its builtin `echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-echo) which doesn't.

To access the `echo` program, rather than the builtin, you can either give a path to it:

```
/bin/echo --help
```

or use Bash's [`enable` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-enable) to disable the built-in version:

```
$ enable -n echo
$ echo --help
```

Bash has built-in versions of a lot of basic commands, because it's a little faster to do that, but you can always bypass them like this when you need to.

Comment: Serves me right for using `zsh`. `enable` does work, though.

Comment: @MichaelHomer So some built-in version may differ from... original ones ? If there are differences, then what's the name for all original commands, including  'echo program'  as you mentioned ? Or what term do we use to distinguish them from built-in versions ?

Comment: @booksee: Yes, they can differ. GNU `echo` in particular has a lot of extensions above POSIX, and Bash's `echo` only a few. There isn't really a general name that I can think of for commands that could be shadowed by builtins. There aren't so many that you'd need one: `echo`, `test`, `[`, and `pwd` are the ones you're likely to encounter.

Comment: @Gnouc: Yes, `command` explicitly does call builtins always. I don't know what I was thinking, other than that `zsh`'s works the other way.

Comment: "use Bash's enable command to disable" yup, guys, is like that

Comment: @boksee: in bash, use `type -all echo` to see which one is used (and what others there are visible, builtin/alias/function/in the path)

Comment: @MichaelHomer and @Gnouc: in bash `command something` bypasses and alias -or- function named "something", but not builtins. `\something` only bypass alias. so indeed `enable -n something ; command something` would ensure you call the one in the PATH (wherever it is, if any)

Comment: I throw `$(which echo) --help` into the ring.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to other answers, you can use

```
$ help echo
```

too see a brief help for built-in `echo` command.

Answer (score 9):

You are using the `echo` built-in command of bash, which does not understand the `--help` option. Use:

```
/bin/echo --help
```

To see the help for the built-in `echo`, use `man bash` and search for `echo`.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are 2 echo program: echo (GNU Bash) and echo (GNU Coreutils).

**echo (GNU Bash)**

- to find out echo (GNU Bash) you could using this commands `help` or `help echo`
- to run echo (GNU Bash) just try using echo

```
echo "Hello World"
echo -e "line 1\ttab\nline2"
echo --help --> return error "--help"
echo --version --> return error "--version"
help echo
```

**echo (GNU Coreutils)**

- to find out echo (GNU Coreutils) you could using this commands

```
dpkg-query --listfiles coreutils | egrep '/bin/|/sbin/'
man echo
which echo
```

- to run echo (GNU Coreutils) you should call `/bin/echo`

```
/bin/echo "Hello World"
/bin/echo -e "line 1\ttab\nline2"
/bin/echo --help --> return GNU Coreutils help
/bin/echo --version --> return GNU Coreutils version
help /bin/echo --> return error
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to write a tcsh shell script with `echo -ne` commands in it.

From `/bin/echo --help`:

> For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'echo invocation'

From `info coreutils 'echo invocation'`:

> Due to shell aliases and built-in `echo` command, using an
> unadorned `echo` interactively or in a script may get you different
> functionality than that described here.  Invoke it via `env` (i.e.,
> `env echo ...') to avoid interference from the shell.

So, the solution is to prepend `env` to your echo commands in the script. For example:

`env echo -ne 'Hello\r'`